# Using NFC chip PN532 on RPi 2 model B

Tags: pi-2, nfc

First of all, please bear with me as I'm very new to electronics!

I'm trying to scan NFC tags with my Raspberry Pi and use that (ideally) from a NodeJS project. The NFC chip I bought is [this one](https://www.amazon.fr/gp/product/B014QZRF2U/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o03_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1&tag=gein0f-21) (it's an NXP PN532 chip, I think.)

My progress so far is that I managed to connect the chip to the RPi in I2C mode and use the `nfc-poll` command from **libnfc**. I'm not sure I can get the data stored in the tag, though -- I know it's correctly stored because I can read it from my phone, it's a simple URL.

What I would like to do is control the chip from a NodeJS program -- I saw several npm packages for doing that but I'm not sure about their stability or maturity. If not possible or too hard in Node, I could switch to Python, but the rest of my program, an Express server, is in Node.
This is the part I can't manage. I've read a lot of tutorials and whatnot online, it seems to be difficult and I don't really know what I'm doing and it upsets me. I'm not even sure my choice of chip is good, because I see a lot of references to an Adafruit shield or NFC Explorer but I can't seem to find much on the chip I bought.

So to sum up, I'm a bit lost on what I should do. I understand there are several modes to run the chip (I2C, PSI and UART). UART seems to be the best option but I'm not even sure how I should connect the chip to the RPi to use it.

Is anyone willing to help get this through?

Thank you :-)

Comment: you need to be able to read the tag using the example program (if one is available) before you can even start thinking about NodeJS  .... you can find a lot of questions at SE where people are trying to run a complicated program when the basics do not work

Comment: 1) On Amazon it is tagged with "Arduino". 2) "it's an NXP PN532 chip, I think" - You are not sure???

Comment: @Fabian 1) I came across different posts where people managed to make it work on a Raspberry. Although the images looked different, it always said PN532 so I thought it was juste that the chip was integrated bu some other manufacturer (like a GPU chip that can be integrated into different graphics cards). 2) that's what the article page says on Amazon, but I came to doubt everything now.

Comment: @jsotola I managed to contact the chip in the CLI, as I said. But I can't get further than that.